# Secure way to use password in java file

Tags: java, android, security, android-xml

I am developing an android application through which i am sending a mail via GMAIL API.
To send mail via GMAIL API i have to give them my ID and password.

```
GMailSender m = new GMailSender("myemailhere@gmail.com",
            "mypasswordhere");
```

and i know writing password like this is not at all safe as my password could easily be stolen by extracting my apk and also
storing the password in strings.xml is also not secure as xml can also retrieved.

my question is-
**Is there any other way to write password in my file so that it remain secure??**

Comment: And the easiest answer is no. It's not safe to store passwords on the device.

Comment: With enough time and effort an attacker will be able to find your password

Comment: encrypt your password

Comment: Try this. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending

Comment: @fastsnail And where to store the passwort to decrypt the password?

Comment: @fastsnail and where do you store the decryption key?

Comment: @AhmedNawaz store decrypted password is only secure than just store in a file as a plain text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is not. You **shouldn't** store your password anywhere in the code or in any file.

Even if you encrypt it like someone said you will have to store it's decryption algorithm/key somewhere in the code, which will be easily reverse engineered.

Comment: that someone is me.but i mean it's only better than store as plain text .because encrypted password need to decrypt.it's only good than store as a plain text.in any client login(expect servers) System have to store passwords in anywhere .i said in that case it's better to encrypt .so attacker need more works

Comment: You're right. Systems have to store passwords anywhere. Except that they don't store it in plain text. They store a salted hash of it. And then they compare both of them. Also the OP asked `so that it remain secure` and the answer is still **NO**

Answer (score 2):

No,It's not safe to store passwords on the device.
small advice is always store passwords in char[] in encrypted form rather than storing in a String whenever it is mandatory to store.

Since Strings are immutable in Java if you store password as plain text it will be available in memory until Garbage collector clears it and since Strings are used in String pool for re-usability there is pretty high chance that it will be remain in memory for long duration, which pose a security threat. Since any one who has access to memory dump can find the password in clear text and that's another reason you should always use an encrypted password than plain text. Since Strings are immutable there is no way contents of Strings can be changed because any change will produce new String. So Storing password in character array clearly mitigates security risk of stealing password.

Answer (score 0):

Storing passwords is not considered safe, and shouldn't be done if at all avoidable. There are a few considerations, if you have to for some reason.

1. The best place to store such things is in private SharedPreferences. These are not readable by anything but the app, or rooted devices. Do not store on external storage!!!
2. Encryption can always be undone, but if you have to, then it would be better than nothing, requiring more work to undo. Use a key which is unique to each device.
3. Some sort of a token, such as is used by Oauth, could be a solution. This isn't perfectly secure either, but it could be.
4. Google provides more secure APIs for it's functions. You really should look in to that.